# How to execute a command when left clicking a sword

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to play a sound when I left click a sword using command blocks, but I cannot seem to get it to work when I set a scoreboard objective with stat.useItem.minecraft.iron_sword

Comment: Command blocks only? You can't, IIRC. This is a trivial task with mods/plugins, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can't detect it like that, since the useItem.minecraft.iron_sword statistic only increases when the sword actually hits something (and loses durability).

Instead, you could use an item such as a fishing rod, since it can detect right-clicks.
But if that doesn't help, then you will have to use plugins or mods.